# Getting metadata by NSFileManager

Tags: objective-c, macos, metadata, nsfilemanager

I am working with NSFileManager and I am able to get the file's last update, creation date, ... but I am not able to get when was the last time the file was opened. Is there any way to get this information?

And other question, I get the MIME by the pathExtension property, but this way I get for example .pdf, .doc, ... instead of application/pdf, application/doc, text/txt, audio/vmw, ...is any way to get this information automatically?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: I afraid you cannot get information when the file was opened last time. The closest info to that is modification date (NSFileModificationDate). And I'm thinking you cannot find out MIME type from that file, but if you know it's for example .pdf you can create some custom library to return string application/pdf, etc. I believe you can download files with most of the MIME types.

Comment: ok thanks a lot, not the best news but thanks ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Spotlight's MDItem API to get all the info

```
NSString *path = @"/Users/dominik/Downloads/Screen Shot 2013-11-28 at 13.26.04.png";
MDItemRef item = MDItemCreate(NULL, (CFStringRef)path);
NSArray *attributes = (NSArray*)CFBridgingRelease(MDItemCopyAttributeNames(item));
NSDate *date = (NSDate*)CFBridgingRelease(MDItemCopyAttribute(item, kMDItemLastUsedDate));
CFRelease(item);
NSLog(@"%@",attributes);
NSLog(@"%@",date);
```

Comment: relies on the file being indexed by spotlight

Answer (score 1):

I think NSURL's  [NSURLContentAccessDateKey](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURL_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000301-SW3) may be close to what you are after and may help depending on what you are actually doing..

But it is **accessed** not **opened**.

Which means for example:

if you **open** the file it is accessed.

If you **quicklook** the file it is accessed.

> NSURLContentAccessDateKey The time at which the resource was most
>   recently accessed, returned as an NSDate object if the volume supports
>   access dates, or nil if access dates are unsupported (read-only).
>   Available in OS X v10.6 and later. Declared in NSURL.h.

Example:

```
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification
{

    [self lastAcccess:@"/Users/UserName/Pictures/screenshots/text.png"];
}



- (void) lastAcccess: (NSString *) the_path  {

    NSURL *theUrl = [NSURL  fileURLWithPath:the_path];
    NSError * error;

    NSDate  *theDate;
    [theUrl getResourceValue:&theDate forKey:NSURLContentAccessDateKey error:&error];

     NSLog(@" theDate %@", theDate);

}
```